# Semantic error in the selection condition of the type of LED lamps

Tags: c++, class

I have a class of light bulbs. There are methods and constructors in this class. There is even a destructor) The problem is that I have to determine and display information about class members with type "n" in the TEST() method (LED lamps).
To implement this task, he developed the gettype() method, which returns the type of an object, and, in fact, the TEST() method, which displays information about light bulbs.

The problem is that nothing works for me. I tried a lot of things, but it doesn’t work out for me to implement this task. I'm new to programming (

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class lamp 
{
public:
    // methods
    void TEST(void);
    char* gettype (void);
    void INIT(void);
    void SHOW(void);
    // construcrors
    lamp();
    lamp(const char *t, int powe, const char *c, double cos);
    lamp(const lamp & obj);
    // destructor
    ~lamp();
private:
    // data
    char type[100]; // LED, energy-saving or incandescent lamp 
    int power;      // LED lamp - "n"
    char color[100];
    double cost;
};

lamp::lamp() {
    cout << "This object was created in the default constructor.\n";
    strcpy(type, "");
    power = 0;
    strcpy(color, "");
    cost = 0;
}

lamp::lamp(const char *t, int powe, const char *c, double cos) {
    cout << "This object was created in the constructor with parameters.\n";
    strcpy(type, t); //*t
    power = powe;
    strcpy(color, c); //*c
    cost = cos;
}

lamp::lamp(const lamp & obj) {
    cout << "This object was created in the copy constructor.\n";
    strcpy(type, obj.type);
    power = obj.power;
    strcpy(color, obj.color);
    cost = obj.cost;
}

lamp::~lamp() {
    cout << "Deletion of object by destructor.\n";
}

void lamp::SHOW(void) {
    cout << "Lamp Information:\n";
    cout << "\nType > " << type;
    cout << "\nPower > " << power;
    cout << "\nColor > " << color;
    cout << "\nCost > " << cost << endl;
}

void lamp::INIT(void) {
    cout << "Enter lamp information:\n";
    cout << "\nType (if LED, then n) > "; cin >> type;
    cout << "\nPower > "; cin >> power;
    cout << "\nColor > "; cin >> color;
    cout << "\nCost > "; cin >> cost;
}

char* lamp::gettype (void) {
    return type;
}

void lamp::TEST(void) {
    cout << "\nType > " << type;
    cout << "\nPower > " << power;
    cout << "\nColor > " << color;
    cout << "\nCost > " << cost << endl;
}

void main() {
    setlocale(0, "");

    // default constructor for 1 class instance
    lamp l1;
    cout << "Entering data for the first product." << endl;
    l1.INIT();

    // constructor with parameters for 2 class instances
    cout << endl << "Information about the second object: \n"; 
    lamp l2("n", 950, "yellow", 1580);

    // copy constructor for the third object
    cout << endl << "Information about the third object: \n";
    lamp l3(l2);

    // Derived information about all the lamps using the method SHOW
    l1.SHOW();
    l2.SHOW();
    l3.SHOW();

    // I create an array of two objects using the default constructor
    lamp la[2];
        I enter data into an array of objects using the method INIT
    cout << "Fill an array of objects with 2 elements." << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        la[i].INIT();
    }
        // I output data from an array of objects using the method SHOW
    cout << "Showing items." << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        la[i].SHOW();
    }

    // looking for and displaying information about LED lamps
    cout << "Search and display information about LED lamps." << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (la[i].gettype() == "n") {
            cout << endl << " lamp number : " << (i + 1) << endl;
            la[i].TEST();
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: I looked for a sentence ending in a question mark and didn't find one.  What do you want to know?

Comment: If you use "C strings", you need `strcmp` rather than `==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your code：

1. `strcpy` is included in `<cstring>` which is missed. You need to add it in the beginning:

```cpp
#include <cstring>
```

2. `main()` function should be declared as `int main()` and you need to add a `return` statement

```
int main() {

    //YOUR CODE HERE

    return 0;
}
```

3. You missed a comment sign at line 104

```
    lamp la[2];
    //I enter data into an array of objects using the method INIT
    cout << "Fill an array of objects with 2 elements." << endl;
```

After fixed, your code should be able to run.